# How do I get an Excel macro to copy data from a specific column and the same row that is selected at activating macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

Example:
I have selected any row and any column, let's say D6.
The data I am looking for is in column H.
So, I want the macro to copy the data in row 6, and column H, i.e. H6.

If I have selected G14, the macro shall copy the data in cell H14, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy
 ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
```

call it on Worksheet_SelectionChange

if you only want the value to use, just assign

```
Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
```

to a variable and use it in your calculations and return where you will

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a macro for that. It always copies the selected cell and pastes the data on column H at the same row.

```
Sub NewMacro()
    Selection.Copy
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 8).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Not really what I asked for, but it still might be a part of a solution. I want to copy the value in column 8 of the row I have selected (selected a cell). Then I am to use that value in further calculations... maybe: 

Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 8).Select
Selection.Copy

etc
I'll try it!

Answer (score 0):

You've had a few days so may have reached an answer already, but extending the answer already suggestedn, I think the below will do what you ask:

```
Sub CopyFromColH()
    'Save the current location
    Dim TargetCell As Range
    Set TargetCell = ActiveCell.Range("A1")

    'Copy from same row in H
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 8).Select
    Selection.Copy

    'Paste to original location, as saved above
    TargetCell.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: datatoo's later suggestion is much cleaner (and more efficent; simply better, really) so I suggest using that!
I'd vote datatoo's answer up if I could, but I lack the reputation at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("U:U")) Is Nothing Then
    Cancel = True

    If Application.CountIf(Sheets("AA").Range("L:L"), Target.Value) = 0 Then
      Cells(Target.Row, 12).Value = Target.Value
    End If
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Farrakh. Welcome to SO. Please consider adding some description to your answer to help us to understand your solution